# Sub/superscript using <sub> and <sup> incorrectly displayed

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

In the past I have been using `<sub>` and `<sup>` for subscript and superscript in questions and answers. While writing an answer yesterday, I noticed that superscript no longer worked as expected. Both subscript and superscript created with the `<sub>` and `<sup>` tags are shown as small letters with the same baseline as the normal text (or at least that's what I see on my computer).

> This is a test of <sub>sub</sub>script and <sup>super</sup>script.

Below is a screenshot of the above text as I see it now:

> [image: subscript and superscript example]

Was something changed to the vertical-align of 'sub' and 'sup' in the Stack Overflow CSS, or should I look for the cause of this problem in my own setup?

When I view other sites the superscript and subscript looks normal, e.g. [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/sup).

Comment: Yep. Looks like `vertical-align: baseline` got added to the global reset for all elements at the very beginning of the CSS file (my local version of the file doesn't have it). Probably didn't realize those two elements were in the list and depended on that baseline change.

Comment: This answer looks weird now https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296077/sandbox-archive/184672#184672

Comment: Was about to ask this question also. +1. This affects this answer also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492302/easy-interview-question-got-harder-given-numbers-1-100-find-the-missing-numbe?rq=1

Comment: On MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296134/sup-superscript-html-tag-has-ceased-to-work-correctly

Comment: Interestingly, superscript and subscript render just fine on mobile (at least, they do as I write this). I'll be really grateful when you fix the formatting bug on the browser version: Typing all those tags was a pain, and I'd hate to think it was all for naught. (MathJax would be so much nicer. But it's true there is a lot you can do with the available HTML tags. Or could do, anyway.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

We've been updating some CSS and it seems like we missed something there. Fix is in repo waiting for build. Give it a couple hours please. And sorry for the issue!

Comment: No problem. I'm relieved it was an error and not a decision to deprecate the tags.